# Como adicionar novos encodings em python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou tentando instalar o [pybraces](https://github.com/thatch/pybraces) mas não consigo.
Como faço para instalar-lo ?

Estou usando python 2.7 e windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você não deveria instalar o "pybraces" - se quer aprender Python,  recomendo aprender Python e não instalar uma modificação à linguagem que vai trorna-la não padrão. Se você realemtne usar o Pybraces vai usar algo que não é igual a Python para quem sabe Python, e não é igual à linguagens derivadas de "C" com java e Javascript, que usam  "{" e "}" para delimitar blocos.

Aliás, como não é um projeto extensivamente testado dificilmente terá sequer suporte sintático às declarações que usam chaves normalemente no Python como dicionários, conjuntos, dict comprehensions e set comprehensions.

Ademais, nenhum exemplo de Python que vocẽ encontrar na internet (ou no stack overflow) vai funcionar.

Se "{" e "}"  são  tão importantes para você, talvez seja melhor estudar Javascript em vez de Python.

Dito isso, as instruções para instalação estão no README, no próprio link que você colocou:

```
You'll need to copy or symlink braces.py into your Python lib/encodings
directory, and ensure that your user has rights to create the .pyc or .pyo
file there.
```

Ou seja, simplesmente coloque o arquivo `braces.py` na pasta `lib/encodings` de sua instalação de Python - e declare o encoding de cada arquivo com `# coding: braces` na primeira linha.

O próprio projeto do Pybraces avisa que ele é "silly": uma forma de poder colocar "{" e "}" necessários às linguagens

Comment: Eu só quero instalar para ver como é (curiosidade).